# Is there a way to see created by , last modified by in feild definition using tooling api, metadata api or other ways in Apex?

Tags: metadata-api, tooling-api

Is there a way to see created by , last modified by in feild definition using tooling api, metadata api or other ways in Apex?[image]

Comment: What is your higher-level goal that you're trying to accomplish? Please edit your question.

Comment: The goal is to provide a consolidated view by custom page for admins , so that they can see a list of the fields ,who created them, and who modified them and when.  this opens up great opportunity for admins to better manage their orgs. e.g. one can run a report and show how many fields are created or modified in the past month, and who did that. ..

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/319559/retrieving-audit-fields-of-a-custom-metadata-type-object - this will work for any custom object. (The example uses custom metadata type)

Comment: Thanks, I had also checked this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible and the fields are available via tooling api in the link below:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_system_fields.htm
These fields are system fields and their information is not in the documentation of the FieldDefinition table, which was why I raised this question.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Label,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate FROM FieldDefinition WHERE PublisherId != 'System' AND EntityDefinitionId = 'Opportunity'

[image]